# Creat a searchable PDF automatically from an other PDF or image

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr, acrobat-sdk

I need to create an application or a script that lets you create a searchable PDF from another PDF or image.
I tried to use Adobe Acrobat's SDK, but I don't found a solution to use Acrobat's OCR feature in an other application.

Do you have another solution, or can you give me help for Acrobat's SDK??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Acrobat SDK is primarily here to create plug-ins for Acrobat, which means that Acrobat has to be run, and the plug-ins are restricted by the restrictions you find in Acrobat (such as the non-ability to run as a service).

A small scale solution might be creating an Action in Acrobat which does OCR.

For a independent application and/or a service, you would have to use one of the libraries floating around, or see whether there are possibilities with dedicated OCR applications, such as Abbyy FineReader (which is said to be superior in OCR than Acrobat, for example).

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use Acrobat in my C# codes